# How to preserve order of data in dataprovider?

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

**Situation:** I have two tests a() and b(). b() is made to depend on a() using "dependsOnMethods" parameter. I have different sets of data for both the tests. Is there a way to ensure that the order of data is preserved when executing the tests?

**Example:**

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
    return new Object[][] {
        { "Google" },
        { "Microsoft"}, 
    };
}

@DataProvider(name = "test2")
public Object[][] createData2() {
    return new Object[][] {
        { "Apple"},
        { "Yahoo"}, 
    };
}


@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1) {
    System.out.println(n1);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "test2", dependsOnMethods="verifyData1")
public void verifyData2(String n1) {
    System.out.println(n1);
}
```

I would like the result to always be 
Google,Apple, Microsoft,Yahoo.
or
Microsoft,Yahoo,Google,Apple

but not
Google,Yahoo,Microsoft,Apple, or Google,Microsoft,Apple,Yahoo.

This means if test1 is run using the first set of parameters from its dataprovder, test2 should also be run with the first set of paramaeters from it's dataprovider.
It does not matter if the second set of params in dataprovider for test1 is run before the first set, as long as the second test also runs with the second set of params from its dataprovider before running the first set. Is there a way to achieve this?

Just realized that this could be fixed by using group-by-instances parameter. (an option I dint find in my testng xml because I was using the old version.). I am going to try upgrading my testNg and post an update.

Comment: I upgraded my test-ng version to 6.8.8, and used group-by-instances, but it did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The testng first runs the 'verifyData1' method for all data received from date provider, and after that it will run 'verifyData2', so the output will be: Google, Microsoft, Apple, Yahoo

Comment: I understand that is the default behavior. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: that's correct it is stated in doc:
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Answer (score 0):

See http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Dependent methods are grouped by class. If method b() depends on method a() and you have several instances of the class that contains these methods (because of a factory of a data provider), then the invocation order is:
    
    `verifyData1("Google")
    verifyData1("Microsoft")
    verifyData2("Apple")
    verifyData2("Yahoo")`

TestNG will not run b() until all the instances have invoked their a() method.

If you would like ordering:
    
    `verifyData1("Google")
    verifyData2("Apple")
    verifyData1("Microsoft")
    verifyData2("Yahoo")`

You can use XML attribute **group-by-instances** :
    
    `<test name="Test1" group-by-instances="true">`